# Detect “Save Password to iCloud Keychain” prompt before resuming

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, auth0, keychain

Is it possible to detect when the "Would you like to save this password in your iCloud Keychain" prompt is presented/dismissed from an `SFSafariViewController`? If so, how?

My use case is that I'm authenticating users with Auth0 and when the service calls my callback URL, the application delegate is given the URL (via `application(_:open:...)`) and at that point, the prompt is presented. Resuming the authentication session by passing along the authorization code in the URL finishes the process, which dismisses the Safari view controller which in turn dismisses the save password prompt before the user even gets to interact with it.

I'd like to delay resuming the authentication session if the prompt is presented, giving the user time to select an option, and continue resuming the authentication after they've made a selection. So in short, I need to know if it is currently presented, and then be notified when it is dismissed.

This is the prompt I'm referring to, just for more context:
[image: "System prompt that asks the user if they would like to save this password in their iCloud Keychain"]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a limitation because auth0 uses ASWebAuthenticationSession